# How do I write the date to a .txt?

Tags: python, list, datetime, text-files

**I am trying to write the date to a .txt file. The following is the code that I have made to do this but it always gives me an error.**

```
import datetime

mylist = []
today = datetime.date.today()
mylist.append(today)
print mylist[0]

file = open('Date.txt', 'a')
file.write(mylist)
file.close()
```

**This code gives me the following error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Volumes/CHROME
>   USB/STORAGE/Date.py", line 9, in 
>       file.write(mylist) TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not list

**Will someone please give me an example of a working code?**

Comment: What's your interpretation of the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only write strings, it is stated in the error.
So you can do this to write the liste (converted in string) into the txt file:

```
file.write(str(mylist))
```

**Simple example**

```
>>> a= [1,2,3]
>>> b = str(a)
>>> b
'[1, 2, 3]'
>>> f = open("data","w")
>>> f.write(b)
>>> f.close()
>>> 
$ cat data
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @gian848396 So why do you say that the "answer" is the other one?

Answer (score 1):

`File#write` expects a string, not a list. Try `file.write(repr(mylist))`.

Comment: Yes. I looked through the documentation but could not make very much sense of it since I am still a novice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write the contents of the list, do it like this:

```
for entry in mylist:
    file.write(str(entry))
```

or

```
map(lambda x: file.write(str(x)), mylist)
```